# Custom compression tool

Tags: python, compression

I have made my own compression tool for a *stack-based language* that uses a dictionary compression method. The code for the decompression is the following:

```
elif current_command == "\u201d":
    temp_string = ""
    temp_string_2 = ""
    temp_index = ""
    temp_position = pointer_position
    while temp_position < len(commands) - 1:
        temp_position += 1
        try:
            current_command = commands[temp_position]
            if dictionary.unicode_index.__contains__(current_command):
                temp_index += str(dictionary.unicode_index.index(current_command))
                temp_position += 1
                pointer_position += 2
                current_command = commands[temp_position]
                temp_index += str(dictionary.unicode_index.index(current_command))
                if temp_string == "":
                    temp_string += dictionary.dictionary[int(temp_index)].title()
                else:
                    temp_string += " " + dictionary.dictionary[int(temp_index)].title()
                temp_index = ""
            elif current_command == "\u201d":
                pointer_position += 1
                break
            elif current_command == "\u00ff":
                temp_string += str(pop_stack(1))
                pointer_position += 1
            else:
                temp_string += current_command
                pointer_position += 1
        except:
            pointer_position += 1
            break
        if debug:print(str(pointer_position) + " with " + str(hex(ord(current_command))))

    stack.append(temp_string)
```

The temporary variables are `temp_string`, `temp_string_2`, `temp_index` and `temp_position`. I know I should not be using names like these, but I didn't know what else to name it. This code just doesn't feel clean, and I don't know if it's just me, but it's not pleasant to look at. The code above can be found [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/05AB1E.py#L263). The `dictionary.unicode_index` is found [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/dictionary.py#L10002).

The best way to explain this is with an example:

For example, we want to compress the sentence `Hello, World!`. We first look at the index of the word `Hello`, which has [index 2420](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/dictionary.py#L2420). Since the language is 0-indexed, we need to substract 1 from this, leaving 2419. We now slice this into two pieces, 24 and 19. Then we find the corresponding indices, found [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/Info.txt#L126).

```
24 gives Ÿ
19 gives ™
```

The concatenation of the indices is done at this part:

```
temp_index += str(dictionary.unicode_index.index(current_command))
```

After the concatenation, we search up the index in the dictionary, which is done here:

```
if temp_string == "":
    temp_string += dictionary.dictionary[int(temp_index)].title()
else:
    temp_string += " " + dictionary.dictionary[int(temp_index)].title()
```

We append a comma, and we repeat the process for the next word, which is `World`. This has the [index 119](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/dictionary.py#L119). Again, substract 1, which gives us the following compressed word: `Œ‰`. This gives us the following code for my language:

```
”Ÿ™,Œ‰!
```

And decompresses to `Hello, World!`, which can be verified [here](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdxbjihKIsxZLigLAh&input=).

I was wondering how I can make the code look more clean, because right now, it looks like a complete mess.

Comment: No comment for the close vote from VTCer + question looks reasonable = Vote to leave open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need better constants - `"\u201d"` is too magic - I would have no idea that it is a right double quotation mark just looking at that.

Don't use a bare `except` - you'll catch things you don't want to (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).  Also, narrow the `try` as much as you can - if it is this big, it will be very hard to tell what caused the error. You should strongly prefer catching specific errors over all errors - errors you aren't expecting are probably bugs, and you'll want to learn about them.

Instead of calling `__contains__` use `in`.

Don't use string concatenation the way you are - that's gonna be wasteful. Instead, use `string.join`.

You also don't need to forward declare all of these variables.

Using a format string will help the debug section be clearer.

You probably also want to factor out the first `if` branch into its own function, but given that it seems a little similar to the outer branch and the loop.  My guess is that the entire function this is in could be redesigned to be simpler and more modular, however without seeing that I can't speak exactly to it.

If you always increment `pointer_position`, put it in a `finally` block.

Overall, I'd recommend something more like this

```
elif current_command == "\u201d":
    compressed_strings = []
    position = pointer_position
    while position < len(commands) - 1:
        position += 1

        try:
            current_command = commands[position]
            if current_command in dictionary.unicode_index:
                position += 1
                pointer_position += 1
                next_command = commands[position]

                f = lambda x: str(dictionary.unicode_index.index(x))
                index = f(current_command) + f(next_command)

                next_string = dictionary.dictionary[int(temp_index)].title()

                compressed_strings.append(("" if not compressed_strings else " ") + next_string)
            elif current_command == "\u201d":
                break
            elif current_command == "\u00ff":
                compressed_strings.append(str(pop_stack(1)))
            else:
                compressed_strings.append(current_command)
        except Exception:
            break
        finally:
            pointer_position += 1
        if debug:
            print("{} with {}".format(pointer_position, hex(ord(current_command))))

    stack.append(''.join(compressed_strings))
```

Comment: That looks a lot better than my code. Thanks for the tips :).